# C programming queue without using pointer

Tags: c, email

Hi everyone i am new to this site..
my question as below

Queues are commonly used in network systems. For example, e-mail is placed
in queues while it is waiting to be sent and after it arrives at the recipient’s
mailbox. A problem occurs, however, if the outgoing mail processor cannot
send one or more of the messages in the queue. For example, a message might
not be sent because the recipient’s system is not available.
Write an e-mail simulator that processes mail at an average of 40 messages
per minute. As messages are received, they are placed in a queue.
For the simulation assume that the messages arrive at an average rate of
30 messages per minute. Remember, the messages must arrive randomly,
so you need to use a random-number generator to determine when messages
are received (see “Queue Simulation,” starting on page 175).
Each minute, you can dequeue up to 40 messages and send them.
Assume that 25% of the messages in the queue cannot be sent in any processing
cycle. Again, you need to use a random number to determine
whether a given message can be sent. If it can’t be sent, put it back at the
end of the queue (enqueue it).
Run the simulation for 24 hours, tracking the number of times each
message had to be requeued. At the end of the simulation, print the statistics
that show:
a. The total messages processed
b. The average arrival rate
c. The average number of messages sent per minute
d. The average number of messages in the queue in a minute
e. The number of messages sent on the first attempt, the number sent on
the second attempt, and so forth
f. The average number of times messages had to be requeued (do not
include the messages sent the first time in this average)

however, since my C basic is weak, i create my own algorithm which i think i mayb manage to do it... and here is my algorithm

//my own algorithm to do this question

1. declare 40 elements (use as mail) sample : 40 mails in waiting list to be send (queue it)
2. output like"mail[1] has been sent"
   1.random generate whether a mail success send or nt
   2.( using randomnum%4, if remainder =0,1,2 success , else fail)
3. if fail, requeue the mails
4. statistic 
   1.run the program once , get all the data like (msg sent in time then * 24) 
   2.get the time for all msg to be successfully sent and then get the statistic for 24 hours
   2.output the data on screen

data
-(msg sent in time then * 24 to get 24 hours data)
-number of msg sent in 24 hours, change per minutes

here is my work now
//my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 500

int queue_array[MAX];
int rear=-1;
int front=-1;
void insert(int add_item);
void delet(int add_item);
void display();

int main()
{
    int element[40],i,j;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=0;i<40;i++)
    {       
        element[i]=rand();
        insert(element[i]);
        j=element[i]%4;
        if (j==3)
        {
        printf(" Mail failed to send. \n");
        delet(element[i]);
        insert(element[i]);
        }
        else
        printf(" Mail success to send.\n",j);
        delet(element[i]);
    }
    display();
    return 0;
}

void insert(int add_item)
{
    if(rear==MAX-1)
    {
    printf("Queue Overflow \n");
    }
    rear=rear+1;
}

void delet(int)
{
    if (front==-1 || front>rear)
    {
        printf(" There is no mail in queue now. \n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        front=front+1;
    }
}

void display()
{
    int i;
    if(front==-1)
    {
    printf(" All the email in queue have been sent.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Queue is : \n");
        for (i=front;i<=rear;i++)
        printf("%d",queue_array[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically that's not a valid C program... The `main` function must be declared as always and explicitly return an `int` and either take no arguments (use `void`) or take an `int` and an `char *[]`.

Comment: hi @JoachimPileborg thx for your reply.. i am new to C with very weak basic.. now i jus want to make this program works only ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thereare a few strange things there, and probably because of them the program does not work. First of all as Joachim Pileborg said, I quote "The main function must be declared as always and explicitly return an int". That means that instead of just `main()` it should be at least `int main()`.
The second reason is because `void insert(int)` function probably should be `void insert(int add_item)` if of course you want to use the passed value to this function. Same thing goes for `void delet(int)`.
Third is using element[i] berfore initialising it. In your code first `insert(element[i])` is called, but at that moment the whole array `element[i]` is uninitialized. It gets initialized with `element[i]=rand()` only on the next line. All in all this part of code

```
    insert(element[i]);
    element[i]=rand();
```

Should probably look like

```
    element[i]=rand();
    insert(element[i]);
```

Fourth actually comes from second and third. `void insert(int)` function does not do anything with the passed value. Instead it adds an uninitialised value of int to the `queue_array`. `int add_item` which is added to `queue_array` is not actually connected to the passed value, and it is not initialized before it is added to `queue_array`. I guess that you wanted to add a value that is passed to a function, so as i said `void insert(int)` actually has to be something along the lines of `void insert(int add_item)`. Also if my previos assumption about `insert()` is correct, then you do not need `int add_item;` inside the function. All in all this part of code

```
void insert(int)
{
    int add_item;
    if(rear==MAX-1)
```

should probably look like

```
void insert(int add_item)
{
    if(rear==MAX-1)
```

Also there is a problem with if(rear==MAX-1) check - Right now your program will output a warning message about the overflow of the queue and still try to another element to the `queue_array` which will lead to failure, because `queue_array` has no more elements. In simple word it means that it will try to put `add_item` elemet to the `queue_array[500]`, but will fail because `queue_array[500]` does not exist. So probably this part of the code

```
if(rear==MAX-1)
printf("Queue Overflow \n");
```

Should probably look like something like this

```
if(rear==MAX-1)
{
  printf("Queue Overflow \n");
  return;
}
```

As it stands now `delet(int)` function does not do anything at all. It does not delete any elements, it only modifies `front` variable. If it should do this, although i strongly think it is somewhat wrong, then you do not have to pass any values to `delet(int)`, which actually implies that it should look like `delet()`. But that is one big assumption.

The `void display()` function actually seems to be fine in theory, and should at least work somehow, when you fix all other things.

The last thing is actually this - I am not sure that you actually need `front` variable. If you want to build a FIFO(first in, first out) queue for your messages it can be done using only `rear` variable, although it would not be somewhat simple.

In the end i would suggest to draw on paper, the things you want to happen to `queue_array` upon the calls of `insert` and `delete` functions and write them from scratch. The drawing will actually help you to get the idea of what `insert` and `delete` functions should do, and how they should do it.

Comment: first, thank you so much @Eugene Anisiutkin for helping to improve my coding.. i know it is kinda messy >< i have go through ur explanation on part 1,2 and 3(including the void insert function) and i already modify it based on ur explanation... however i still nt clear about how should i modify my delet function to make sure my code is working... btw here is my code after modify.. i trying to make everything easier to understand and to fulfill the requirement of the question...

Comment: I have already edit my coding and i posted it above... can u go through it and c as if any mistake I not yet change? your help is appreciate..

Comment: the modification of these functions actually depends on what you want them to do). There can be several possible implementations, but they are dependant  on the logic you want to implepent into these functions. Trust me when i say a paper and a pencil will help firgure out the logic, the code writing after that will be easier =)

Comment: I'll post some fixes as a separate answer, which will allow it to at least compile and somehow run)

Comment: okok thank you...i will take ur advice to finish this assignment, thx again...have a nice day!! =)

Comment: good luck with the program)

Answer (score 1):

Well i made some fixes, some of them i pointed out. The code below will compile and will Run, but still i have no idea if it's output is the desired one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 500

int queue_array[MAX];
int rear=-1;
int front=-1;
void insert(int add_item);
void delet();
void display();

int main()
{
    int element[40],i,j;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=0;i<40;i++)
    {
        element[i]=rand();
        insert(element[i]);
        j=element[i]%4;
        if (j==3)
        {
            printf(" Mail failed to send. \n");
            delet();
            insert(element[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" Mail [%d] was sent successfully\n",j);
            delet();
        }
    }
    display();
    return 0;
}

void insert(int add_item)
{
    if(rear==MAX-1)
    {
        printf("Queue Overflow \n");
        return;
    }
    rear=rear+1;
    queue_array[rear] = add_item;
}

void delet()
{
    if (front==-1 || front>rear)
    {
        printf(" There is no mail in queue now. \n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        front=front+1;
    }
}

void display()
{
    int i;
    if(front==-1)
    {
    printf(" All the email in queue have been sent.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Queue is : \n");
        for (i=front;i<=rear;i++)
        {
            printf("%d",queue_array[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```